# nuxtjs : how to force page reload and call asyncData()?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

In my NuxtJS SSR project with bootstrap-vue as frontend :

1. I have some page with template and default component
2. In component there is  **asyncData(context)** function  that makes some deal before component render and mounts

Everything is working fine, except only one thing, I need reload (or refresh) a page after some interval automatically  and call **asyncData** again. Standard js  **window.location.reload()** is not good solution, because it`s reloads fully page. I want refresh in vue style, when only changed components re-rendres. I tried to call **$nuxt.refresh()** but no any effect

Some code example (cut from real project ) , page "index.vue" :

```
<template>
  <div>
  <b-tabs content-class="mt-3">
    <b-tab  title="Test" active><shdashboard searchtype="test"> </shdashboard></b-tab>
  
  </b-tabs>
</div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name : "index",
  async asyncData (context) {

if(process.server)
    {

    const host = "http://SOMEHOST";
    const http = context.$http;
    const data = await  http.$get(url);

    console.log('in server render')
  
     /* 
     some logic
     commit store and prepare data fot b-tab component

      */
     }
   },
methods : {

    refresh() {
         console.log("method refresh")
          this.$nuxt.refresh(); // Not any effect. 
                }
      },
  mounted() {
   console.log("page mounted");
   setInterval(()=>{

    /*
     I need to reload page every 15 sec, and call asyncData() to get new values for
      <b-tab> component
       
    */

    this.refresh();
   },15000);
}
</script>
```

What do I wrong ?

Comment: in javascript `location.reload()` will reload the page...

Comment: Thanks, I know. But its reloads a whole page. I need refresh it. I want same effect if I change a component data in vue SPA.  Or like nuxt router, when you change url, its looks like change components, but not staticaly reload

Comment: so why don't you call a store that fetches data regularly instead? why do you need to reload?... unless you give us the real example, it's hard to understand what are you trying to do, maybe explain the why as there are maybe better ways to accomplish the same?

Comment: Because in application logic, there is some functions that need to be done before render a page. I can do with rest call, but I had implemented same logic in asnycdata().

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1133

Comment: TL;DR: Async only works as intented on pages, not in components.

Answer (score 0):

One way, if I understand your issue correctly, is to use the Vuex store for storing whatever you are fetching in `fetch`/`asyncData`. That way you don't need to worry about the internals of Nuxt.js, and what hooks are triggered when.

I.e. something like this:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    someData () {
      return this.$store.state.someData
    },
  },
  async asyncData ({ store, $axios }){

    let data = await $axios.$get(endpoint)
    store.commit('setSomeData', data)

  },
}
```

Then just use `{{ someData }}` in your template!